# Storing and updating current days database records in local storage

Tags: jquery, asp.net, html

I hope this makes sense, but I have an asp.net web forms application that I want to work offline.

I thought about creating a stored procedures, queries to bring down data that would be used on that day (like scheduling, jobs etc.) and store it in the mobile devices local storage.

Then I thought I could update the data and then synch when internet was available or when user chooses.

I guess I would need some kind of marker to let me know that the data is no longer needed.

Does this make sense?
If it does make sense, does anyone have any recommendations on where to start.
If it doesn't make sense, does anyone have any suggestions on what to do?

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand the question correctly, you have an *existing* asp.net web forms application that you want to work offline, and it looks like you want it to be able to be used on a mobile device.  I don't know how you would do this with the application *as-is*, since asp.net is, by definition, server-side.

If I was going to do something like that, I think what I would do is just make an html page with the offline functionality in jQuery (or javascript).  Then I would create a asp.net library with the online functions that I need and a page to return results.  I would then use jQuery AJAX calls to interact with the library to read and write information when online.

There are probably better ways to do it - I don't know anyone else who does this - but this is a method I've used successfully before to interact with .Net code through a plain html page. This way you could at least reuse a lot of the existing .net code if you have to start over.

Depending on the application, you could also just separate them.  The HTML Page with jQuery that works offline would be your main form, and then just make the link to the existing web forms app only available when online.

I hope this helps a little.  Maybe someone will come up with a better answer.